# Bash scripting with skeleton in Debian

Tags: linux, bash, debian

Before of first, I'm a Linux (administrator|developer) newbie.

I need to run a bash script every 5 seconds, it's very simple; export service's information to text files.

I try to do this with cron daemon, but it's run every minute at least.

I'm discover Skeleton script and have many questions about this:

- I need write some special code in my bash file?
- How to run every 5 seconds?
- There are a best practices manual?

Comment: You cannot do this cron based, crons resolution is indeed limited to 1 minute. Instead you need to implement your own simply daemon that triggers the required action based on events generated by the systems clock. You want to take a look at the `sleep` commands and similar.

Comment: I want to avoid cron @ElmoVanKielmo, and I want to do this as a daemon.

Comment: Then read the linked question and __especially__ the accepted answer. It's clearly said there that cron should not be used for this and bash code is posted as well.

Comment: Ok @ElmoVanKielmo, now I understanding. I'm in debt with you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its not possible through cron as daemon runs once in every minute. Or when job list is modified

Put whatever you want to run in a script inside infinite while loop and put sleep of 1 sec
something like

`while [ 1 ] 
do
run_your_cmds here
sleep 1
done`

BUT I dont think anything need that kind of monitoring.

Best Practice!!
Please dont try and do it with cron.